# Spring 4 Application Close Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I want to programmatically shut down my Spring 4 application.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Now, how do I close this?

I cannot use - `((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();` because it gives Cast Exception.

So how can the application be shut down?

I cannot declare the following:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext_Web.xml");
```

because that would create a new application context, whereas I want to close an existing context.

Comment: If it is a web application shutting down the context only partially shutsdown the application, leading to strange exceptions. So not sure if that really is wha tyou want.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to shutdown your Spring application you can use the Spring Boot Actuator.

This Spring subproject contains an endpoint `shutdown` who lets the application be gracefully shutdown.